# Missing df --direct option?

Tags: oracle, df, gnutls

during configuration (after install) of Oracle XE 18c on my 16.04, I noticed this message generated by the shell script:

```
/bin/df: unrecognized option '--direct'
'Try '/bin/df --help' for more information.
```

I'm not sure how important it is for the install, the script goes on asking for the password to be set on system users...

ANYWAY the point for me it's that the **--direct** option is available on other linux versions, for example [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df), it seems to be part of the standard GNU utility, but I supposed that I've already got it as part of the Ubuntu 16.04 distro.

Anybody could please clarify this?  Is there a way to obtain the same behaviour with my current version of **df**?
Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:  The target server is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 has reached `End of Life`. Please consider an upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: Ok, but could you confirm that in 16.04 the 'df --direct' option works?

Comment: I'm on 18.04 currently and the `--direct`-option is not known, so I guess in 16.04 it will be the same.

Comment: You could try removing `--direct` from the installation script and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I've exchanged the old and the new machines, the server I'm trying to configure is the 16.04...  @mook765 your guess is right.  I'm editing the question to correct this. The problem is on the 16.04 too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--direct` is an option that got added to `df` in version 8.4.6 so your download of Oracle XE 18c is not intended for 16.04. You probably need an older release or (as @jos mentioned) edit the script. See below for the old option we use.

```
* Mon Mar 29 2010 Kamil Dudka <kdudka@redhat.com> - 8.4-6
 - a new option df --direct (#479364)
```

There is no Ubuntu yet that goes higher than 8.30 (and that includes [eoan](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&keywords=coreutils))

On Ubuntu 16.04 we use 8.25 and the equivalent is called `--output=avail` ([gnu coreutils df](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/df-invocation.html#df-invocation))

```
$ df --version
df (GNU coreutils) 8.25
```

Comment: Thank you, @Rinzwind, I modified the install script but not having a 'df --direct' output to compare it with the 'df --output=avail' I'm still not 100% sure if it's working the expected way.  Now I'm getting another error about the amount of shared memory, but that's another story...

Comment: /vendor/bin/df -h